# Operation Status: src_is_MTP_in_another_mirror_session

Tags: aruba

I am having problems with the aruba switch as I would like to create a mirror port that has 1/1/1 as its source and 1/1/6 as its destination, I have no other mirror session active and yet the problem persists
here there is no reference about: https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/AOS-CX/AOSCX-CLI-Bank/cli_10000/Content/Chp_Mirror/Mirror_cmds/sho-mir-10.htm?Highlight=mirror
here's my mirror configuration:

Mirror Session: 1

Admin Status: enable

Operation Status: src_is_MTP_in_another_mirror_session

Comment: listen I-O

Source: interface 1/1/1 both

Destination: interface 1/1/6

Output Packets: 139783210684416

Output Bytes: 139783307550168

interface 1/1/6

no shutdown

no routing

vlan access 1

interface 1/1/1

no shutdown

no routing

vlan access 1

the version of the software i'm using is a ArubaOS-CX Virtual.10.07.0010